# Only mapping from department side is mapped and not from inverse side.How can i say this is a Many to Many

Tags: java, hibernate

Below is the code

```
 package com.hibernate.mapping.mtm;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

    /**
     * @author Prajapati
     *
     */
    public class Main {


        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SessionFactory sf= new Configuration().configure("com/hibernate/mapping/mtm/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            Session sn  = sf.openSession();
            Transaction tx = sn.beginTransaction();


            Department dept1  = new Department();
            dept1.setId(20l);
            dept1.setDepartmentName("Development");


            Department dept2  = new Department();
            dept2.setId(10l);
            dept2.setDepartmentName("Accounts");

            Department dept3  = new Department();
            dept3.setId(30l);
            dept3.setDepartmentName("QA");

            Department dept4  = new Department();
            dept4.setId(40l);
            dept4.setDepartmentName("Designing");


            Employee emp1 = new Employee();
            emp1.setEmployeeID(30l);
            emp1.setEmployeeName("Michele");

            Employee emp2 = new Employee();
            emp2.setEmployeeID(40l);
            emp2.setEmployeeName("Devendra");


            Employee emp3 = new Employee();
            emp3.setEmployeeID(50l);
            emp3.setEmployeeName("Prabhat");

            Employee emp4 = new Employee();
            emp4.setEmployeeID(60l);
            emp4.setEmployeeName("Himanshi");

            Employee emp5 = new Employee();
            emp5.setEmployeeID(70l);
            emp5.setEmployeeName("Kanika");


            List<Employee> employeesQA = new ArrayList<Employee>();

            employeesQA.add(emp3);
            employeesQA.add(emp2);


            List<Employee> employeesDev = new ArrayList<>();

            employeesDev.add(emp3);
            employeesDev.add(emp4);


            List<Employee> employeesAccounts = new ArrayList<>();

            employeesAccounts.add(emp5);
            employeesAccounts.add(emp1);




            dept3.setEmployees(employeesQA);
            dept1.setEmployees(employeesDev);

            List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>();

            departments.add(dept1);
            departments.add(dept2);
            departments.add(dept3);
            departments.add(dept4);

            //emp5 works in all the departments
            emp5.setDepartments(departments);


            /*List<Department> departments3 = new ArrayList<Department>();

            departments3.add(dept1);
            departments3.add(dept2);

            emp3.setDepartments(departments3);
             */


            sn.save(emp5);
            sn.save(dept3);
            sn.save(dept1);

            /**
             * When i am running this program. 
             * Only mapping from department side is mapped and not from inverse side.How can i say this is a M2M 
             * while i am unable to Map from both the sides in terms of Hibernate
             */

            //      sn.save(p);
            tx.commit();
            sn.close();


        }

    }
```

---

```
package com.hibernate.mapping.mtm;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;


    @Entity
    public class Department {

        @Id
        private Long id;


        private String departmentName;

        //@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="departments")
        @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Employee> employees;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getDepartmentName() {
            return departmentName;
        }

        public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
            this.departmentName = departmentName;
        }

        public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
            return employees;
        }

        public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
            this.employees = employees;
        }



    }
```

---

```
package com.hibernate.mapping.mtm;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private Long employeeID;

    private String employeeName;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="employees",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    //Mapped by says here that go to employees in opposite table to get details of departments for employees and the key of the relationship is on the other side.
    //i.e. you are considering department side the owner side now by saying mappedby.
    //@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Department> departments;

    public Long getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(Long employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public List<Department> getDepartments() {
        return departments;
    }

    public void setDepartments(List<Department> departments) {
        this.departments = departments;
    }




}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mapping</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>


        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

     <mapping class="com.hibernate.mapping.mtm.Employee"/>
    <mapping class="com.hibernate.mapping.mtm.Department"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

I am very confused over why didn't Hibernate saved all the entries for emp5 as it is in all the departments and the relationship is many to many
    there is no entry done for the employee emp5.

Below are the tables with respective data:

```
mysql> select * from employee;


    | employeeID | employeeName |


    |         40 | Devendra     |

    |         50 | Prabhat      |

    |         60 | Himanshi     |

    |         70 | Kanika       |



    mysql> select * from department;



    | id | departmentName |


    | 10 | Accounts       |

    | 20 | Development    |

    | 30 | QA             |

    | 40 | Designing      |

    mysql> select * from department_employee;



    | departments_id | employees_employeeID |

    |             20 |                   50 |

    |             20 |                   60 |

    |             30 |                   50 |

    |             30 |                   40 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The association is bidirectional. A bidirectional association has two sides: the owner side, and the inverse side. Hibernate doesn't care about the inverse side when persisting. It only considers the owner side. The owner side is the side which does NOT have the `mappedBy` attribute. So, the owner side here is `Department`.

Your code adds dept1, dept2, etc. to emp5. But it doesn't add emp5 to dept1, dept2, etc.

So not only does your code make the object graph incoherent (if dept1 is in emp5's departments, then dept1 should have emp5 in its list of employees), but it only initializes the side that Hibernate doesn't care about.

Comment: Thanks jb nizet,But relationship is many to many and must be applicable from both the sides, why inverse side can't be persisted.Also, when i just saved emp5 why all departments get saved but not he relationship in them.

Comment: The fact that it's many to many doesn't change anything. There is an owner side, and there is an inverse side. It's your responsibility to make the graph coherent, and to at least modify the owner side of the association if you want it to be persisted. There's no way around it. That's how it is.